# SHA1 passwords in MySQL, field clears on edit

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sha1

I'm trying to figure out how to better store SHA1 passwords in MySQL.  I'm experiencing a weird issue where the field is being cleared when any other field is edited using the phpmyadmin GUI.

[image]

The 'pass' field is VarChar[40] with utf8-bin charset.  Everything works fine, until I click edit:

[image]

The password field does not populate in the editor, and therefore saves as empty.  Any ideas about what is happening?

Comment: You can use HeidiSql, it seems a configuration issue with phpMyAdmin

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: 3.4.5.  But I just updated to 3.4.10.1 and was able to reproduce.

Comment: These are ancien phpMyAdmin versions, can't you update to a more recent one?

Comment: As Marc says, those are old phpMyAdmin versions. With 3.5.8, I am unable to reproduce.

Comment: So I upgraded to 4.0.9.  It appears to only happen with certain characters, but I have been unable to determine which ones.  This can be reproduced by trying to add 'Ã²B>Ã»Â™Ã’Â–=Ã¤Z'Â€Â€Â‡Ã­Ãƒ' to a varchar field using the GUI, or adding it using a sql command, and attempting to edit the record using the GUI.